# Starting-point of time-series influences regression?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I've used tslm() under the R-package fpp to analyse two time series, which seem similar:

```
library(fpp)
a<-ts(c(1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,2,21,4,6,8,10,11,12,13,14,18), start = c(1959, 1), frequency=12)
b<-ts(c(1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,2,21,4,6,8,10,11,12,13,14,18), start = c(1959, 3), frequency=12)
```

However, the results of a simple time series regression

```
summary(tslm(a~trend+season))
```

and

```
summary(tslm(b~trend+season))
```

look different - why isn't this the same? How can the trend be the same, but the other results be different? I'd understand shifted seasonal results, but these are really different.

Idea: the function tslm() expects full years, thus for time series b months jan and feb '59 as well as the rest of 1960 are filled with values computed from the given data. But is that idea true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are identical as you would expect.

```
> summary(tslm(a~trend+season))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   3.8264     3.3251   1.151   0.2742  
trend         0.3819     0.1516   2.519   0.0285 *
season2      -0.8819     4.4590  -0.198   0.8468  
season3       4.2361     4.4667   0.948   0.3633  
season4      -4.1458     4.4796  -0.925   0.3746  
season5      -3.0278     4.4975  -0.673   0.5147  
season6      -1.9097     4.5205  -0.422   0.6808  
season7      -0.7917     4.5483  -0.174   0.8650  
season8      -0.1736     4.5811  -0.038   0.9704  
season9       0.4444     4.6185   0.096   0.9251  
season10      1.0625     4.6607   0.228   0.8239  
season11      1.6806     4.7073   0.357   0.7278  
season12      3.7986     4.7583   0.798   0.4416  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.456 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6231,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2119 
F-statistic: 1.515 on 12 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.2495

> summary(tslm(b~trend+season))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   5.5069     4.0710   1.353   0.2033  
trend         0.3819     0.1516   2.519   0.0285 *
season2       2.1181     4.4590   0.475   0.6441  
season3      -1.6806     4.7073  -0.357   0.7278  
season4      -2.5625     4.6607  -0.550   0.5934  
season5       2.5556     4.6185   0.553   0.5911  
season6      -5.8264     4.5811  -1.272   0.2297  
season7      -4.7083     4.5483  -1.035   0.3228  
season8      -3.5903     4.5205  -0.794   0.4439  
season9      -2.4722     4.4975  -0.550   0.5935  
season10     -1.8542     4.4796  -0.414   0.6869  
season11     -1.2361     4.4667  -0.277   0.7871  
season12     -0.6181     4.4590  -0.139   0.8923  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.456 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6231,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2119 
F-statistic: 1.515 on 12 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.2495
```

First note that the last three lines of output are identical in both cases, and that the trend coefficient is identical. So the only differences are in the parametrization of the seasonality and intercept. If we add the intercept to each seasonal dummy, you will see the simple shift in seasonality as you would expect.

```
> beta=coefficients(tslm(a~trend+season))
> beta[1] + beta[3:13]
   season2    season3    season4    season5    season6    season7    season8 
 2.9444444  8.0625000 -0.3194444  0.7986111  1.9166667  3.0347222  3.6527778 
   season9   season10   season11   season12 
 4.2708333  4.8888889  5.5069444  7.6250000 
> beta=coefficients(tslm(b~trend+season))
> beta[1] + beta[3:13]
   season2    season3    season4    season5    season6    season7    season8 
 7.6250000  3.8263889  2.9444444  8.0625000 -0.3194444  0.7986111  1.9166667 
   season9   season10   season11   season12 
 3.0347222  3.6527778  4.2708333  4.8888889
```